# Expressjs: ENOENT when uploading image

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, express

I have written some middleware for uploading an avatar, like this:

```
var gm = require('gm'),
    mkdirp = require('mkdirp'),
    fs = require('fs');

uploadAvatar = function(req, res, next) {
  var img, path, user;
  if (req.files.avatar_image) {
    user = req.user;
    img = req.files.avatar_image;
    path = __dirname + "/../../public/avatar/" + (user.name.parameterize()) + ".png";
    mkdirp.sync(__dirname + "/../../public/avatar/");
    fs.createReadStream(img.path).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
    gm(path).resize(250, 250).autoOrient().quality(90).write(path, function(err) {
      if (err != null) {
        req.flash('error', err);
      } else {
        user.avatar = "/avatar/" + (user.name.parameterize()) + ".png";
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err != null) {
            req.flash('error', err);
          }
          next();
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

// Usage
app.post('/upload', ensureAuthenticated, uploadAvatar, handleUpload);
```

When I now try to upload an image, `node` crashed with the incredibly helpful error message:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/tmp/1126846a248af5c584770b07de649f9b.png'
```

I have tried copying the file before using `gm` on it, too. I suspect that express deletes the file before I can even touch it, as a "security".

Can anyone help me here?

**EDIT**: [Full source](https://gist.github.com/scan/a0a5ae2d4957bfe79b12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all copy temp file to your avatar directory, and second make sure that you have permissions on avatar as well as temp directory and files.

As well piping read to write stream is not sync operation, and you will try to pipe straight after initialising read handle, that might lead to some problems.
You need to add events and wait till file get copied:

```
var complete = function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    // process your gm
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

var read = fs.createReadStream(sourcePath);
read.on('error', function(err) {
  complete(err);
});

var write = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);
write.on('error', function(err) {
  complete(err);
});
write.on('close', function() {
  complete();
});
read.pipe(write);
```

Comment: Please look at the gist I added and tell me what I am doing wrong. I *am* copying the file before resizing.

Comment: Check permissions for temp directory, and its parent and so on. In order to ensure that user that is running node process has rights to access files in temp folder.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just found out the temp directory did not exist. No idea why.